How to poll a redis++ subscriber
I am using redis++ for an application with a redis backend. We rely on pubsub for some communication between different processes.
Currently, we use socket_timeout and a loop to consume messages. This has some drawbacks however.

If other work comes in (not via redis) it can only be handled after the socket_timeout expires
I cannot check if the subscriber has a message without blocking

After looking at the source code it does not seem to hard to expose the hiredis filedescriptor via the Connection class.
In the ideal case I would like to run a select/poll call on that fd and some others, but I could would already be happy if I could just query a subscriber if work is ready.
Before I start the work, I was wondering if this is a known problem or if I am looking at this the wrong way.


If other work comes in

Do you mean that you need to do a subscribe or psubscribe call?
If you use the sync version of Redis::Subscriber, YES, you have to wait until socket timeout or you can have another process/thread publish a message to the channel to wake the blocking customer.
Another solution is using the AsyncSubscriber. With this class, you can subscribe or psubscribe channels without waiting until socket timeout.

The process is mainly doing other processing, not from redis. This process only use a redis pubsub to notify a config change throughout a distributed system. So it is just subscribed to a single channel. It just needs to poll it in between each piece of work, I prefer not to do this in a new thread since that required synchronization between threads, Also this feels like overhead since a poll/select call on the fd does not require extra threads. Also, the AsyncSubscriber requires a rather big rewrite of the code. We might look at hiredis instead but I really like redis++.
